# Replacement of Angular's $rootScope in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating a demo app in Angular 2 and I stuck in this app. I want to use a global variable/object throughout the app like `$rootScope` in angular. Please suggest me what to do to achieve this?
Currently, I am using  `EventEmitter`.

**app.component.ts:**

```
<a routerLink="/admin" routerLinkActive="active" style="float:right;"
    *ngIf="currentUrl != '/admin'" (adminUrl)="setUrl($event)"  >Admin-{{currentUrl}}</a>

 `@Output()  adminUrl:String;`
```

**heroes.component.ts:**

```
  @Output() adminUrl = new EventEmitter();
  this.adminUrl.emit(this.router.location.path());
```

The above code is not all code, this is for understanding that what I am doing to achieve for the same.

Comment: Use a shared service https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: In my app. I am using dashboard which is loading once when app is started. But I want to do like, in the dashboard, there is a link "admin "  and want show this link when Url would be other than '/admin', but when the URL will be '/admin' then I don't want to show this link. The problem is that Dashboard is loading only once and in the dashboard, *ngIf="adminUrl!='/admin' "   value of adminUrl would change on every route change but here (in the dashboard ) value retain same. Please suggest what I can do?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985009/angular-2-what-is-equivalent-to-root-scope .A much better solution

Answer (score 1):

you can use localStraogeService to use a global variable/object throughout the app 
first of all you have to install localStorage in your project by

```
npm install angular-2-local-storage
```

then import it into your baseComponent if you have

```
import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular-2-local-storage';
```

then just inject in the constructor of BaseComponent

```
constructor(protected localStorageService: LocalStorageService)
```

then you can get and set the value of `localStorageService` by

```
this.localStorageService.set('sessionData',{Object});
```

and get by

```
 this.seesionDetails = this.localStorageService.get('sessionData');
```

you can also follow the things from the below link to achieve localStorageServices

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-2-local-storage
```