# Angular2 Global Variable service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

i am trying to make a global variable to handle when to show the loader on my website. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985009/angular-2-what-is-equivalent-to-root-scope) but i get the following errors.

Generic Type 'Observer' requires 1 type argument(s) on this line

```
this.ShowLoaderChange = new Observable((observer:Observer){
```

also i can't seem to see where they declared the variable for the ChangeObserver as i am using here:

```
this.ShowLoaderChangeObserver = observer;
```

and here

```
this.ShowLoaderChangeObserver.next(this.ShowLoader);


import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class LoaderService {
  public ShowLoader;
  ShowLoaderChange: Observable<any>;

  constructor() {
     this.ShowLoaderChange = new Observable((observer:Observer){
         this.ShowLoaderChangeObserver = observer;
     })
  }

  setData() {
    this.ShowLoader = !this.ShowLoader;
    this.ShowLoaderChangeObserver.next(this.ShowLoader);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**:
After changing my code as per the answer below and it making sense it get TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined in [null]
this comes from the line

```
this.ShowLoaderChangeObserver.next(this.ShowLoader);
```

I am calling the function like this

```
import {LoaderService} from '../LoaderService'
export class AdminDashboardComponent implements OnInit{
constructor (private loader:LoaderService){}

ngOnInit():any{
   this.loader.setData();
```

}
}

**EDIT: NEW SERVICE**

```
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class LoaderService {
   public ShowLoader: boolean;
   ShowLoaderChange: Observable<boolean>;
   ShowLoaderChangeObserver: Observer<boolean>;

   constructor() {
      this.ShowLoaderChange = new Observable((observer:Observer<boolean>) 
     => {
         this.ShowLoaderChangeObserver = observer;
        })
   }

  setData() {
      this.ShowLoader = !this.ShowLoader;
      this.ShowLoaderChangeObserver.next(this.ShowLoader);
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the type of value that your observable will yield as the type parameter. In your case since you have typed your observable as `ShowLoaderChange: Observable<any>`, you can specify the type of your observer as any as well:

```
this.ShowLoaderChange = new Observable((observer:Observer<any>) => {
    this.ShowLoaderChangeObserver = observer;
});
```

---

But looking at your code you can probably type your observable as `boolean` and avoid using `any` since you are only yielding boolean values from your observer:

```
export class LoaderService {
  public ShowLoader: boolean;
  ShowLoaderChange: Observable<boolean>;
  ShowLoaderChangeObserver: Observer<boolean>;

  constructor() {
     this.ShowLoaderChange = new Observable((observer:Observer<boolean>) => {
         this.ShowLoaderChangeObserver = observer;
     })
  }

  setData() {
    this.ShowLoader = !this.ShowLoader;
    this.ShowLoaderChangeObserver.next(this.ShowLoader);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this makes more sense to me. The only problem is now i am getting an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined in [null] on the line this.ShowLoaderChangeObserver.next(this.ShowLoader);

Comment: How are you calling `setData`? Is `this` pointing to `LoaderService` instance inside `setData` and at `this.ShowLoaderChangeObserver = observer;`?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this. Can you see what you have for `this` in `setData` and inside `(observer:Observer<any>) => {
    this.ShowLoaderChangeObserver = observer;
}`

Comment: i am then calling service.setData() in my component Child. I did also bootstrap my LoaderService