# AngularJS $rootScope.$on alternative in context of migration to Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angularjs-rootscope

Our AngularJS project had start it's long way to the modern Angular.

The `ngMigration` util recommend me to remove all the `$rootScope` dependecies because Angular doesn't contain a similar concept like `$rootScope`. It is pretty simple in some cases but I don't know what to do with event subscription mechanisms.

For example I have a some kind of Idle watchdog:

```
angular
    .module('myModule')
    //...
    .run(run)

//...       
function run($rootScope, $transitions, Idle) {
    $transitions.onSuccess({}, function(transition) {
        //...
        Idle.watch(); // starts watching for idleness
    });

    $rootScope.$on('IdleStart', function() {
        //...
    });

    $rootScope.$on('IdleTimeout', function() {
        logout();
    });
}
```

On which object instead of `$rootScope` I have to call the `$on` function if I want to get rid of the `$rootScope`?

**UPD**

The question was not about *"how to migrate on Angular2 event system"*. It was about how to remove a $rootScope dependencies but keep a event system. Well it seems to be impossible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 - What is equivalent to Root Scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985009/angular-2-what-is-equivalent-to-root-scope)

Comment: Services is recommended way in latest Angular versions

Comment: This is not exactly the answer I need. But now I have understood that there is no way to have a event mechanism in AngularJS and not to have a $scope and $rootScope at the same time. This is a hard coupled things.

Comment: Hi - I have the exact same question - to remove the usage of rootscope within the AngularJS application so that it will be easy to upgrade. Specifically how to handle the events without scope/rootScope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I don't know what to do with event subscription mechanisms.*

Angular 2+ frameworks replace the $scope/$rootScope event bus with observables.

From the Docs:

> ## Transmitting data between components
>
> Angular provides an [`EventEmitter`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) class that is used when publishing values from a component. `EventEmitter` extends [RxJS Subject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subject), adding an [`emit()`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter#emit) method so it can send arbitrary values. When you call `emit()`, it passes the emitted value to the `next()` method of any subscribed observer.
>
> A good example of usage can be found in the [`EventEmitter`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) documentation.

For more information, see

- [Angular Developer Guide - Observables in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular#observables-in-angular)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `TimeOutService` which will do the log out after x minutes (in this case 15 min) of inactivity or it will reset the timer after certain action(s).

```
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, Subject, Subscription, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { startWith, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AuthService } from 'path/to/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class TimeoutService implements OnDestroy {

  limitMinutes = 15;
  secondsLimit: number = this.limitMinutes * 60;
  private reset$ = new Subject();
  timer$: Observable<any>;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private authService: AuthService,
  ) {
  }

  startTimer() {
    this.timer$ = this.reset$.pipe(
      startWith(0),
      switchMap(() => timer(0, 1000))
    );
    this.subscription = this.timer$.subscribe((res) => {
      if (res === this.secondsLimit) {
        this.logout();
      }
    });
  }

  resetTimer() {
    this.reset$.next(void 0);
  }

  endTimer() {
    if (typeof this.subscription !== 'undefined') {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

  }

  logout(): boolean {
    this.authService.signOut().subscribe((res) => {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
    return false;
  }

  ngOnDestroy():void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

And in the `AppComponent` have listener which will reset timeout on certain actions

> In case as bellow it listens for keyboard strokes, mouse wheel, or mouse click

```
 constructor(
    private timeoutService: TimeoutService
  ) {
  }

  @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  @HostListener('document:wheel', ['$event'])
  resetTimer () {
    this.timeoutService.resetTimer();
  }
```